# All values for Batch Geocode outCols

Tags: geocoding, here-api

There´s a way to receive all output fields using Batch Geocode endpoint?

I´m using this endpoint but I would like get all outCols fields available:
[https://batch.geocoder.ls.hereapi.com/6.2/jobs?apiKey={MY_KEY}&action=run&inDelim=;&outDelim=;&outCols={WAY_TO_GET_ALL_FIELDS}&language=pt-BR&gen=8&header=true&outputCombined=true](https://batch.geocoder.ls.hereapi.com/6.2/jobs?apiKey=%7BMY_KEY%7D&action=run&inDelim=;&outDelim=;&outCols=%7BWAY_TO_GET_ALL_FIELDS%7D&language=pt-BR&gen=8&header=true&outputCombined=true)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
outcols Enumeration, Required   List of columns to return in the output.
```

So in outcols, we will have to provide the list of columns to return in the output.

Refer more details : https://developer.here.com/documentation/batch-geocoder/dev_guide/topics/request-parameters.html

Also , there are  hundreds  of  out put fields  but in customer  use case all are not required at once.

details of all  output fields : https://developer.here.com/documentation/batch-geocoder/dev_guide/topics/read-batch-request-output.html